# Is there a significant performance difference between importing an object that maps icons and importing icons individually?

Tags: reactjs, performance, material-ui, es6-modules

My team is using `@mui/icons-material` in our React project and we're currently importing the same icons to represent the same things in many different components.

**Component A**

```js
import { Group as IconGroup, Person as IconPerson } from '@mui/icons-material';

return <div>...<IconPerson />...<IconGroup /></div>;
```

**Component B**

```js
import { Group as IconGroup, Person as IconPerson } from '@mui/icons-material';

return <div>...<IconPerson />...<IconGroup /></div>;
```

I'm thinking of creating an object that maps *all* of our icons and referencing that instead.

**icons.ts**

```js
import { Group as IconGroup } from '@mui/icons-material';
import { Person as IconPerson } from '@mui/icons-material';

export const icons = {
  collection: <IconGroup />,
  user: <IconPerson />,
}
```

**Component A**

```js
import { icons } from 'icons';

return <div>...{icons.user}... {icons.collection}</div>;
```

**Component B**

```js
import { icons } from 'icons';

return <div>...{icons.user}... {icons.collection}</div>;
```

The advantage is that if we ever want to move away from `@mui/icons-material` or just change an icon, we only need to change it in one place and it would be reflected across all components.

But I am concerned importing a rather large object into so many components may degrade performance. I'm not sure how ESM modules handle that, or if that's even a consideration.

In terms of performance, is it better to import the icons individually? Is there a *significant* difference when importing a shared object that maps them to keys?

Comment: Do not create an object. Use `export const collection = <IconGroup />; export const user = <IconPerson />;` and `import * as icons from 'icons'`

Comment: Is `import *` any different from `import { icons }`? I guess we could create variables for each and then `import { collection, user }`, which would at least give us the same advantage as the object (an abstraction layer).

Comment: Yes, it allows named imports, and it allows bundlers to do proper tree-shaking.